# harddisk of 1 tb with exfat not detected in macbook pro el capitan

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-el-capitan, disk-utility, exfat

My 1 Tb HDD is formatted in EXFAT so it could be detected both in Windows and MacOS. However, the hdd has power blinking but it is not detected in MacOS. It is working well in Windows though. On Mac, I tried different settings in disk-utility, but no luck.

Anyone has any idea on what could be the problem? How may I solve it?

Comment: If it is not visible in `diskutil list`, that means that it's not an FS issue.  You should provide more details on the drive's model and connection type.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Mac with your hdd inserted in it? Via which interface (USB 2.0, USB 3.0, Thunderbolt) your external (I suppose) hdd is connected to Mac?

Comment: @ allijamin my external hdd is usb 3.0 supported and my macbook pro is usb 3.0 supported as well and hope that it has the 3.0 ports i it  . No I didnot try to restart with hdd inserted in it.

Comment: What kind of partition tables does the disk have? MBR? GPT w/ PMBR? Hybrid GPT/MBR?

Comment: @Spiff I had MBR partitioned exfat. And I had partitioned from windows as it cannot be detected by mac.